# Removing rows from an xts object if they fall within a time range

Tags: r, xts

I'm using r to analyse some stock price data, and currently have an xts object containing price at 1 minute intervals spanning multiple days. However, this xts object also contains prices outside of trading hours (8:30-16:30 in this case), and I'd like to remove these values. I can't seem to find information on a function that would allow this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter on time inside an xts. You need the format "THH:mm:ss". Instead of filter out the hours outside the trading hours, you filter on the trading hours.

```
# Filter xts on trading hours (if trading hours are between 08:30 and 16:30)
my_xts["T08:30:00/T16:30:00"]
```

See more examples with `?xts` and `?subset.xts`